# Errors occur during update, usually this is caused by bad update configuration in TAC

Tags: talend

Whenever I open Talend data Integration and select onConnection-"Remote".
I am asked to click on update button stating UPDATE IS REQUIRED.
On click of update button I see the following error.

[image]

Errors occur during update, usually this is caused by bad update configuration in TAC

LOGS:

org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.ProvisionException: Operation details
    at org.talend.core.tis.updatesite.NexusUpdateSiteManager.installPatchesByP2(NexusUpdateSiteManager.java:409)
    at org.talend.core.tis.updatesite.NexusUpdateSiteManager.installUpdateSite(NexusUpdateSiteManager.java:346)
    at org.talend.core.tis.updatesite.NexusUpdateSiteManager.downLoadAndInstallUpdateSites(NexusUpdateSiteManager.java:288)
    at org.talend.core.tis.service.CoreTisService.downLoadAndInstallUpdates(CoreTisService.java:343)
    at org.talend.repository.ui.login.LoginProjectPage.updateStudio(LoginProjectPage.java:1091)
    at org.talend.repository.ui.login.LoginProjectPage$18.widgetSelected(LoginProjectPage.java:974)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4172)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:832)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:808)
    at org.talend.repository.RepositoryService.openLoginDialog(RepositoryService.java:318)
    at org.talend.rcp.intro.Application.logUserOnProject(Application.java:442)
    at org.talend.rcp.intro.Application.start(Application.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)

Contains: Your original request has been modified.

Contains: "Publish Upload" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.

Contains: "Utils Plug-in" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.

Contains: "Libraries Manager Plug-in" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.

Contains: "Joblet Plugin" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.

Contains: "Patch Updates" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.

Contains: "Core Runtime Plug-in" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.

Contains: "Hadoop Cluster plugin" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.

Contains: "FTP Plug-in" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.

Contains: "Model Plug-in" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.

Contains: "Talend Designer ESB Tooling Web Service consumer plug-in" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.
Contains: "Tis Plug-in" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.

Contains: "Export Route Resources Plugin" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.

Contains: "Migration Tool Plug-in" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.

Contains: "Metadata Managment Plug-in" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.

Contains: "HDFS Browse Plug-in" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.

Contains: "Data Integration View Plug-in" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.

Contains: "Remoteprovider Plug-in" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.

Contains: "Commandline Plug-in" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.

Contains: "CodeGen Plug-in" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.

Contains: "Core UI Plug-in" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.

Contains: "Repository Plug-in" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.

Contains: "Edit" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.

Contains: "Svnprovider Plug-in" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.

Contains: "Ui" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.

Contains: "Mapper Component Plug-in" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.

Contains: "Generic Core" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.

Contains: "CDH 5.7.0 distribution" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.

Contains: "CDH 5.5.0 distribution" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.

Contains: "Gitprovider Plug-in" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.

Contains: "Designer Maven" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.

Contains: "Repository Metadata Plug-in" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.

Contains: "HDFS Repository Plug-in" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.

Contains: "Maven Job" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.

Contains: "Repository Local Provider Plug-in" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.

Contains: "Datatools XML Plug-in" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.

Contains: "Sparkprovider" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.

Contains: "Common UI runtime Plug-in" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.

Contains: "Bigdata" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.

Contains: "Talend Merge Interfaces" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.

Contains: "RowGenerator Component Plug-in" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.

Contains: "Talend Merge Plugin" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.

Contains: "Designer Core Plug-in" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.

Contains: "Core Repository Plug-in" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.

Contains: "Repository View Plug-in" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.

Contains: "Git Provider UI" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.

Contains: "Preview Plug-in" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.

Contains: "Core Plug-in" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.

Contains: "Common UI Plug-in" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.

Contains: "Metadata Managment UI Plugin" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.

Contains: "Designer RunProcess Plug-in" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.

Contains: "Logging Plug-in" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.

Contains: "Libraries Manager UI plug-in" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.

Contains: "Change Data Capture Plug-in" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.

Contains: "Import&Export Items" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.

Contains: "Common Runtime Plug-in" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.

Contains: Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.

Contains: Software being installed: SparkStreamingProvider 6.2.1.20170331_1623_patch (org.talend.designer.components.sparkstrprovider 6.2.1.20170331_1623_patch)

Contains: Missing requirement: SparkStreamingProvider 6.2.1.20170331_1623_patch (org.talend.designer.components.sparkstrprovider 6.2.1.20170331_1623_patch) requires 'package org.talend.repository.storm.stormProperties.impl 0.0.0' but it could not be found

Comment: Could you show what the log says ?

Comment: @iMezouar Sure Please find it in the updated description.

Answer (score 1):

**1.)** Make Sure you don't have a corrupted setup file & don't use a installer, that might delete few files.

**2.)** Goto "**Talend-Studio-20160704_1411-V6.2.1**" directory and create a folder called "**Patches**" and place/copy the TPS-1864 zip file inside in it or any zip file from your organization nexus that you see missing in your talend error logs.

**3.)** Now launch the studio with .exe file, you will be prompted for creating a connection, ensure you create local connection and provide the license when prompted.

**4.)** Once the studio is launched, you should be prompted for Update as we have provided the patch to apply. Click update your studio should launch as expected.

**5.)** Second time launch the studio in remote connection.

**DONE :)**